# Deleting files from inside Bash while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

The code below is failing to delete the files which are listed in
the file called ListOfFilesToDelete.txt and it seems strange.

Is there an obvious (to more experienced programmers) or is it
instead that something needed is missing?

When this is run, the screen output shows no errors, so I do not
have much toehold for debugging.

The data in ListOfFilesToDelete.txt is like so: (path+filename)

```
/home/UserB/A_TEST_Destroy/A_Real_Stew/3 Disk Images/F Fundamental/Originals/Picasa.ini  
/home/UserB/A_TEST_Destroy/A_Real_Stew/3 Disk Images/S Single Malts/Picasa.ini
```

Code:

```
touch /home/UserB/PLAY/DeletedFiles.txt  

TheDOOMEDfiles="/home/UserB/PLAY/ListOfFilesToDelete.txt"

while ifs="" read -r LINE
  do
  Doomed=$(echo "$LINE")
  echo "Ok, LINE : $Doomed"
  rm -f $Doomed
  echo "Just Nuked ${Doomed}" | tee -a /home/UserB/PLAY/DeletedFiles.txt

done < $TheDOOMEDfiles
```

Comment: IFS is in upper case.

Comment: On another note, `$(echo ...)` is [UUOE](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use more quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting):

```
rm -vf "$Doomed"
```

Clearly, there are spaces in your files-to-be-deleted path - "3 Disk Images"

Comment: @ anishsane So it was something missing! gosh... *wipes egg off face*